# How to hide the line in a range in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

I want the pgfplots not to show the line between a range. For example, in the following case, the function between 1~2 is not defined and the line should not show. I use the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.16
}
\pgfplotstableread{
                0   0
                1   1
                2   2
                3   3
            }\data
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            unbounded coords=jump,
            x filter/.expression={x>1&&x<2? nan : x}
        ]
            \addplot table {\data};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The above code doesn't work. I think it is due to that there exist no sample points between 1~2. Are there some other approaches can do this?

Comment: @marmot Thanks. But the function between 1 and 2 is not defined and thus no corresponding value.

Comment: Does that matter? If you add `1.1  0` to your data table, that coordinate is removed by your `x filter`, and you get what I think you want.

Comment: I would simply add another coordinate to the table like `1.5 NaN` (and remove the `x filter` line) to achieve your desired result.

Comment: Did one of the tricks help you to solve the question or do you need further assistance?

Comment: @Stefan Pinnow   marmot and  Torbjørn T. and your solutions work. I wonder if there is a automatic way such as specifying the option.

Comment: could you elaborate what you mean with "an automatic way such as specifying the option"?

Comment: @Stefan Pinnow I have a lot of data file. The data files are exported from mathematica. I mean is there a way to specify the options to the `\addplot` command so that I don't need to  modify the data file one by one.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think so. And before you have to do it twice: If the function you want to plot is not defined between 1 and 2 only, you must have data points at the boundaries, i.e. **at** 1 and 2 or at 0.9999 and 2.0001, depending on if 1 and 2 are inside or outside the defined range. Otherwise the line will be broken starting from the last given point (of course).

Comment: @Stefan Pinnow Thanks for your comments and explanations.  By the way, what should I do to accept the comments? I know how to accept the answer but I don't know how to accept the comments. :(

Comment: You can't, but we can close the question as being solved in the comments if this is fine for you, too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.

Comment: @StefanPinnow I think adding an answer based on your comments would be better than closing.

Comment: @AndrewSwann, I don't think that this makes sense here, because the main "problem" of OP is that there is *no data point* in the range in which "the function is not defined". And because I think OP just gave us a dummy table to try to state the problem there can't be given a good/real answer, don't you think so?